# Filters and Gradient colors not getting applied simultaneously for button skin

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, gradient, skinning, linear-gradients

I have created a sample desktop app using Flex 4 in flash builder 4 wherein I am using a button inside BorderContainer.
I have applied skin to button which includes Dropdownshadow,glow filter,bevel-filter and gradient colors.

But I am facing a problem with use of filters and gradient fill simultaneously.
When using filters gradient fill doesnt show up and vice-versa.
Please let me know where I am making mistake.

This is the main.mxml code:

```
<s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="#003C7B" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" height="350" width="450">
    <s:Button id="btn" label="Select" color="white" verticalCenter="0"  skinClass="BlueButtonSkin" horizontalCenter="0"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

The skin class code for filters and gradient fill is as follows:

```
<s:Rect id="backgroundAndShadow" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" radiusX="5" radiusY="5"
        topLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusY="5" topRightRadiusX="5" topRightRadiusY="5"
        bottomLeftRadiusX="5" bottomLeftRadiusY="5" bottomRightRadiusX="5" bottomRightRadiusY="5">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
            <s:GradientEntry  color="#00366E"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="#013A8B" />
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
    <s:filters>
        <s:GlowFilter alpha="0.9"  color="#ffffff" inner="false"  knockout="true"  blurX="8" blurY="8" />
        <s:BevelFilter angle="270" distance="5" />
    </s:filters>
</s:Rect>

<s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="8" blurY="8" alpha="0.5" distance="5" tlRadius="5" trRadius="5" blRadius="5" brRadius="5"
                         angle="45" color="#000000" left="2" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>
<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="75" height="15" 
        topLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusY="5" topRightRadiusX="5" topRightRadiusY="5"
        bottomLeftRadiusX="5" bottomLeftRadiusY="5" bottomRightRadiusX="5" bottomRightRadiusY="5">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke joints="bevel" caps="round" color="#84C2F2" weight="0.3" alpha="0.3"/>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>


<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="center" 
         verticalAlign="middle" 
         maxDisplayedLines="2" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
         left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
</s:Label>
```

Any suggestions on this?

I am attaching the required look for button for reference:

[image: Button image for Reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,finally I have done it...

Played with the code and found this code works fine with what is required:

```
<s:Rect id="backgroundAndShadow2" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
        topLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusY="5" topRightRadiusX="5" topRightRadiusY="5"
        bottomLeftRadiusX="5" bottomLeftRadiusY="5" bottomRightRadiusX="5" bottomRightRadiusY="5">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#4B7CB6" alpha="0.5"/>
    </s:fill>
    <s:filters>
        <s:DropShadowFilter blurX="5" blurY="5" quality="3" strength="0.65" distance="4" />
        <s:GlowFilter blurX="7" blurY="7" quality="3" color="#004DAF"/>
        <s:BevelFilter blurX="1" blurY="1" quality="3" strength="2" highlightColor="#9FC7F5" angle="60" distance="1"/>
        <s:BlurFilter blurX="1.5" blurY="1.5"/>
    </s:filters>
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect id="backgroundAndShadow" left="1.5" right="1.5" top="1.5" bottom="1.5" 
        topLeftRadiusX="5" topLeftRadiusY="5" topRightRadiusX="5" topRightRadiusY="5"
        bottomLeftRadiusX="5" bottomLeftRadiusY="5" bottomRightRadiusX="5" bottomRightRadiusY="5">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient scaleX="51" rotation="90">
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="#013465"/>
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.32156863" color="#013A7F"/>
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" color="#003990"/>
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
    <s:filters>
        <s:DropShadowFilter inner="true" angle="-130" blurX="2" blurY="0.8" strength="0.5" color="#00275C" alpha="0.8"/>
    </s:filters>
</s:Rect>

<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="center" 
         verticalAlign="middle" 
         maxDisplayedLines="2" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
         left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
</s:Label>
```

Modified the skinclass and got the results!

Answer (score 0):

In your `<s:GlowFilter />` you have set the `knockout` property to `true`. So when applying that filter, it literally knocks out the contents of the item that the filter is applied to. Remove that property altogether or you can set it to false, which is the default.

Here's what the [GlowFilter documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/filters/GlowFilter.html) says for the `knockout` property:

> Specifies whether the object has a knockout effect. A knockout effect
>   makes the object's fill transparent and reveals the background color
>   of the document. The value true specifies a knockout effect; the
>   default value is false (no knockout effect).

Comment: yes.the gradient color is appearing but the effect which was required is disturbed.It doesnt show up the way I want.

Comment: Well, that's a whole different question altogether :) I usually have to play with things like that for a while to finally discover the combination of effects/settings that is pleasing. If you're still stuck maybe you can try posting another question that describes the effect you're after (I'm sure I'm making it sound easier than it actually is). PS: I've never found that knockout property to be useful.

Comment: I agree with you Sunil.But if I keep the knockout property as it is, the required look for button is achieved except the gradient fill part.My only concern is to manage both.

Comment: You might try adding another rectangle to your skin. Apply the glow filter (w/knockout) to one rect, and apply the gradient to the other rect. The point being that anything that has the glow filter w/knockout is going to be made invisible.

Comment: Do you have a mockup of the final look that you're trying to achieve? It's hard to visualize what you're after just by looking at the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25331/discussion-between-komalh-and-sunil-d)